# GAS SpreadsheetApp copyTo Contentsonly error

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, google-sheets, runtime-error, paste

I am trying to run the following code line of code (taken from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)):

```
sheet.getRange("D1:D").copyTo(sheet.getRange("D1"), {contentsOnly:true});
```

I am getting the error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

It runs without a problem if I run the code without the contentsOnly bit:

```
sheet.getRange("D1:D").copyTo(sheet.getRange("D1"));
```

I am attempting to copy > paste values as I want to remove the formula that is in the cells.

I thought it could be that I had a Spreadsheet and not a Sheet (I was using openById, whereas the example uses getActiveSheet), but when I added getSheetbyName() to get a sheet instead, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copyTo` is intended to copy on **another** range, I guess the error you get is normal...

You can get the result you want with `getValues()` / `setValues()`

```
var values = sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
sheet.getRange("D1:D").setValues(values);
```

---

### EDIT :

Following Adam's comment (thanks) it appears that the `copyTo` method should work in this case too, take my suggestion as a workaround if it doesn't for you (even if it was probably only a temporary issue)

Comment: The code in this answer is valid, but I disagree with the reasoning that copyTo doesn't work because it is being copied to the same location. I tried the OP's code and it works. I would say it was just a temporary server issue.

Comment: The contentsOnly copy doesn't seem to be reliable. It sometimes works for me, sometimes doesn't - no idea why. Thanks for this workaround, it saved my day.